# Which of these is better semantically?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

In order to make websites more accessible I have been encouraged to use HTML5 tags `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc... to only surround the actual content, but I have a feeling that I might be doing something wrong.

An example body:

```
<header>
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <nav>
            ...
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div>
    <section>
        ...
    </section>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="center">
        ...
    </div>
</footer>

.center {
   max-width: 70em;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
   width: 100%
   background-color: red;
}

footer {
   width: 100%
   background-color: green;
}

body > div {
   width: 100%
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Is it actually better like this?

```
<div id="head">
    <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <nav>
            ...
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
<div>
    <section>
        ...
    </section>
</div>
<div id="foot">
    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: What is that div inside the header/footer/section for? Is it necessary for some reason?

Comment: @MarcinJurazek: Its to center the content within the header....the header style is a whole bar across the screen....but I want the content to be in the middle of that bar when the browser is resized.

Comment: Why can't you use body and center header/section/footer within it?

Comment: Because the header/section/footer currently style the page (different styles for each tag). The style goes across 100% of the width of the page....the content is then centered in that.

Comment: but body is going across 100% of the page width as well :) There is no change between sematic of the markup with or without that div (or the position of them). It's just much more elegant not to use them unless they are really necessary and you are not able to get the same effect without them.

Comment: But I can't give body three different styles. Think of it like this. Header background is red, sections are blue, and the footer is green.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7971/discussion-between-marcinjuraszek-and-ben)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for what is better — `DIV` inside structural elements like `HEADER`/`FOOTER` or structural elements inside `DIV`, it does not matter since `DIV` is common container without any semantic sense at all.

What is really unsemantic/bad-practice in your first example is `center` class name. Class names should reflect purpose of block (`content`, `products`, etc.), not its presentation (`center`, `red`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that `div` elements are not required semantically speaking (maybe you need them for styling?).

`div` is an element without semantic (as its counterpart for inline elements `span`) and you have to use them where there isn't anything better. Even if you give them some semantic with its `id` attribute, that semantic is only known by you and not for, for example, any web search motor (google) or any screen reader (for blind people, for example), because there aren't any definitive conventions about `id` or `class` values.

If you use `header`, `footer` etc, you are giving them semantics. Maybe you want to increase their semantic using some value for the [`role` attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/role-attribute/).

By the way, that `section` surely it isn't needed. Look at what people from [HTML5 Doctor say](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/):

> In HTML 5 you can specifically mark up all the “secondary” content on
>   a page such as navigation, branding, copyright notices, so it feels
>   odd that you can’t specifically mark up the most important part of
>   your page—the content.
>
> But what would be the purpose of marking it up specifically, anyway?
>   If you need to style it, use a div. An assistive technlogy like a
>   screenreader can find the main content because it is the first thing
>   inside a page that isn’t a header, nav or footer.

With a `<div role="main">` you have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better like this:

```
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav>
        ...
    </nav>
</header>
<section>
    ...
</section>
<footer>
    ...
</footer>
```

Or alternatively:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="nav">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    ...
</div>
<div class="footer">
    ...
</div>
```

Why are you being told to add those extra wrapper `div` elements?

Comment: @Ben Why not just style the existing elements?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, did you see the added CSS in the OP?

Comment: @Ben If you're adding elements purely to support styling (ie. they are non-semantic) then worrying about which is the most semantic way to add them is pointless.  There is no 'semantic way' to add non-semantic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<section>
  <header> head content </header>
  main content
  <footer> footer content </footer>
</section>
```

This get's rid of all those silly divs and now you have your header and footer linked to your section like they should be.

Comment: Not what I was aiming for. The code provided is in the `body` tag...the DIVS are there for centering the content in the styled header/footer tags

Comment: @Ben then add that class to the <header> and <footer>

Comment: What class are you talking about?

Comment: `header` and `footer` don't need to be linked to a `section`, they can be a `header` and `footer` for the whole page.

Comment: @robertc indeed they can, I assumed they would not be.